How to make the position of a modal window static when zooming or resizing the screen
The site (written in React, using Typescript and Tailwind) has a modal window. Modal is implemented using the "react-modal" library https://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/ .
With standard browser window sizes, there are no problems with a modal window. However, if the user resizes the window or zooms, the modal window moves relative to its parent component.
I would like the model window to remain static in relation to the parent component (and, accordingly, in relation to the entire page) regardless of zoom or screen size.
ParentComponent.tsx
const ParentComponent = () => {
return (
            <>
              <button
                onClick={...} >
                <Icon/>
              </button>
              <ModalWindow/>
            </>
)
}

ModalWindow.tsx
const ModalWindow = () => {
  return (
    <ReactModal
      ariaHideApp={false}
      isOpen={...}
      onRequestClose={() => {...}}
      style={{
        overlay: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
        content: {
          outline: 'none',
        },
      }}
      className={clsxm(
        'absolute top-[50px] right-[-50px] h-[50px] w-[50px] translate-x-[-50%]  translate-y-[-50%] focus:outline-none'
      )}
    >
    </ReactModal>
  );
};

But when I open the windows to full screen, or apply a zoom greater than / less than 100%, the modal window changes its position relative to the parent component.
I would like to do it in such a way that the modal window does not change its position relative to the parent component

Provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem.

When you specify top and right constraints of an element which has absolute positioning, that element will always maintain the specified space from its parent.
In your case, you have set [top-50px] and [right-50px] of an absolutely positioned element. Therefore that element will only take care of top and right space.
In order to make it static, you need to specify its position along both the axes.
Horizontal as well as vertical.
you can do something like this:


const ModalWindow = () => {
  return (
    <ReactModal
      ariaHideApp={false}
      isOpen={...}
      onRequestClose={() => {...}}
      style={{
        overlay: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
        content: {
          outline: 'none',
        },
      }}
      className={clsxm(
        'absolute top-[50px] right-[-50px] left-[50px] bottom-[50px] h-[50px] w-[50px] translate-x-[-50%]  translate-y-[-50%] focus:outline-none'
      )}
    >
    </ReactModal>
  );
};




try to set the relative position of the parent element
const ParentComponent = () => {
return (
            <div className={clsxm('relative')}>
              <button
                onClick={...} >
                <Icon/>
              </button>
              <ModalWindow/>
            </div>
)
}


In order for position: absolute to take into account the parent's position, you might want to set the parent's position to relative.
position: absolute positions your element relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.
Your question has already been answered here
